# Нужно запустить код ( Run main java ) через телеграмм, я в телеграмме пишу / runMain и ничего не получается

Tags: java, telegram, бот

> public class Main extends DOTNames  {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     try {
>         TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
>         botsApi.registerBot(new TelegramBot());
>     } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
>         e.printStackTr`введите сюда код`ace();
>     } }**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом** // code
> ```
>
> Код который у меня есть
>
> **package org.example;
>
> import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
> import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update; import
> org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
>
> import java.lang.reflect.Method;
>
> public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
>     if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
>         String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
>
>         // Check if the message contains the command to trigger execution
>         if (messageText.equals("/runMain")) {
>             // Execute your code here
>             executeMainMethod(update);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> private void executeMainMethod(Update update) {
>     try {
>         // Get the main method of your class using reflection
>         Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.example.Main");
>         Method mainMethod = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
>
>         // Invoke the main method
>         mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) null);
>
>         // Send a response back to the user
>         sendResponse(update.getMessage().getChatId(), "Main method executed successfully!");
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         sendResponse(update.getMessage().getChatId(), "Failed to execute main method: " + e.getMessage());
>     }
> }
>
> private void sendResponse(Long chatId, String text) {
>     SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
>     message.setChatId(chatId.toString());
>     message.setText(text);
>
>     try {
>         execute(message); // Send the message
>     } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
>         System.err.println("Failed to send message: " + e.getMessage());
>     }
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public String getBotUsername() {
>
>     return "здесь есть название бота ";
> }
> @Override
> public String getBotToken() {
>
>     return "здесь есть токен ";
> }
> ```
>
> }
> **

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]